# How to Inverse and square root of matrix using spectral decomposition in r?

Tags: r

I am using airquality inbuilt dataset in R. I need to calculate the inverse and square root of my covariance matrix using spectral decomposition method.

```
data1 <- airquality
data1frame <- as_tibble(data1)

matr <- cov(na.omit(data1frame))
V <- eigen(matr)$vectors
L <- eigen(matr)$values


A1 <- L[1] * V[,1] %*% t(V[,1])
A1
A2 <- L[2] * V[,2] %*% t(V[,2])
A2
A3 <- L[3] * V[,3] %*% t(V[,3])
A3
A4 <- L[4] * V[,4] %*% t(V[,4])
A4
A5 <- L[5] * V[,5] %*% t(V[,5])
A5
A6 <- L[6] * V[,6] %*% t(V[,6])
A6

sumAll <- A1 + A2 + A3 + A4 + A5 + A6
sumAll
```

sumAll is the spectral decomposition of my matrix matr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the inverse take the reciprocal of the eigenvalues and put it back together.  To get the square root take their square roots.

```
matr <- cov(na.omit(airquality))
V <- eigen(matr)$vectors
L <- eigen(matr)$values

# spectral decomp
Matr <- V %*% diag(L) %*% t(V)
all.equal(Matr, matr, check.attributes = FALSE)
## [1] TRUE

# inverse
Inv <- V %*% diag(1/L) %*% t(V)
all.equal(Inv %*% matr, diag(6), check.attributes = FALSE)
## [1] TRUE

# square root
Sqrt <- V %*% diag(sqrt(L)) %*% t(V)
all.equal(Sqrt %*% Sqrt, matr, check.attributes = FALSE)
## [1] TRUE
```

Alternately if you prefer the form where it is expressed as a sum of eigenvalues times projection matrices which project onto the corresponding eigenspaces:

```
Matr2 <- Reduce("+", lapply(1:6, function(i) L[i] * outer(V[, i], V[, i])))
all.equal(Matr2, matr, check.attributes = FALSE)
## [1] TRUE

Inv2 <- Reduce("+", lapply(1:6, function(i) (1/L[i]) * outer(V[, i], V[, i])))
all.equal(Inv2 %*% matr, diag(6), check.attributes = FALSE)
## [1] TRUE

Sqrt2 <- Reduce("+", lapply(1:6, function(i) sqrt(L[i]) * outer(V[, i], V[, i])))
all.equal(Sqrt2 %*% Sqrt2, matr, check.attributes = FALSE)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you. In the first one for inverse equal check, all.equal(Inv %*% matr, diag(6), check.attributes = FALSE), it should be multiplied by uppercase 'Matr' (spec decomp) becasue lowercase 'matr' is my matrix.

Comment: Either `matr` or `Matr` would work there because they are equal; however, the intention was to use `matr`, as written, because this is showing that `Inv` times the original matrix, `matr`, equals the identity matrix.